# How to configure spring cloud gateway with custom host name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices

I'm using spring cloud gateway in a microservices project.
I have two services that are running locally in my system but in eureka server my hostname is like this `L14532.xyz.com` which is assigned to me by my employer network. In the spring gateway's configuration I have mentioned the routes like this:

```js
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
  application:
    name: APP_GATEWAY
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: users
          uri: lb://USERS
          predicates:
            - Host=L14532.xyz.com
            - Path=/users/**
        - id: providers
          uri: lb://PROVIDERS
          predicates:
            - Host=L14532.cts.com
            - Path=/providers/**
        - id: reviews-streaks
          uri: lb://REVIEWSTREAKS
          predicates:
            - Host=L14532.cts.com
            - Path=/review-streaks/**
logging:
  level:
    web: error
eureka:
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
```

After mentioning the hostname also the request still not getting forwarded and application gateway is trying to find the page in src/resources like `spring mvc` and after not finding the page it is throwing **404 not found error**. And if I not mention the host name application gateway throws "L14532.xyz.com" could not be resolved. And throws **500 Internal Server Error**. And all this goes away if I try this project in my home computer where the host name is `localhost`. How can I solve this error.